# Answer count is un-bolded on some pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The number of answers for a question appears in bold in most cases, but normal when the question has an accepted answer, under the questions tab/view.

The HTML looks like:

```
        <div class="status answered-accepted">
            <strong>1</strong>answer
        </div>
```

and the style is:

```
.answered-accepted strong {
  ...
  font-weight:normal;
  ...
}
```

Removing the "font-weight:normal;" makes it look correct to me. The "top questions" (narrow summary) view does not use a `<strong>` tag, so the count remains bold there.

Comment: I'll look into this. thanks